# c# como proteger la conexión a la base de datos?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, seguridad

Me encanta **c#** pero es terriblemente malo que no puedas conectar con una base de datos.
Hablo de cuando creas una aplicación que luego harás pública para que los demás usen.

Por mas que se codifique, encripte, oculte y todo lo que uno quiera la cadena de conexión, eso no importa. Una persona malintencionada no necesita la cadena de conexión decriptada (y aún así es fácil obtenerla)... tiene a su disposición el mismo objeto de [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) con la conexión abierta para realizar consultas a voluntad.

¿Alguien que me diga la fórmula para proteger la instancia (objeto) y la integridad de cada consulta hacia la base de datos e incluyendo la conexión inicial?

Lo triste de esto es que estaba volviendo real una idea que tuve hasta que me di cuenta que el ejecutable se podía descompilar y de ahí razoné que la base de datos entra en peligro.

Comment: Y que lenguaje puede producir un ejecutable que no pueda descompilarse? y pueda ejecutarse en Windows.

Comment: .Net tiene varios mecanismos para proteger estas cosas como, por ejemplo, la encriptación de las secciones de configuración. Échale un vistazo a estos enlaces [Proteger la información de conexión](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/89211k9b(v=vs.110).aspx), [Tutorial: Cifrar la información de configuración mediante la configuración protegida](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dtkwfdky.aspx)

Comment: ¿Has valorado la posibilidad de utilizar servicios Web en lugar de una conexión directa a la base de datos?

Comment: Te refieres a, por ejemplo, en php crear una api?

Comment: Estoy desde el celular. Los he leído pero no he entendido muy bien como aplicarlo.. puedes proporcionarme un ejemplo un poco mas claro? Sobre todo de la autenticación de Windows y sobre el segundo tutori al

Comment: Creo que debo darme por vencido, aceptar que simplemente no se puede hacer lo que quiero y debo desarrollar una api para lo que quiero hacer.
El tema de la api es que cualquier persona con conocimientos podrá darse cuenta que el sistema está echo en base a una api y podrá interactuar a voluntad (limitada obviamente) con ella pero no me gustaría que integren la api de mi sistema a otros sistemas de ellos.

Comment: Hola Lucas, no entiendo muy bien esto último que dices, quizás deberías modificar la pregunta y aportar algún detalle más de lo que quieres hacer e incluir algo de código que sirva para ilustrar el problema. Saludos

Comment: con que tecnologias desarrollas cliente y servidor ? porque poner el connection string en la aplicacion cliente cuando esto sera publico (no es correcto) solo seria valido si vas a usar seguridad integrada con windows. El cliente es winforms y en el servidor solo tienes la base de datos ?

Comment: El cliente es una aplicación de escritorio.
Luego tengo una base de datos + un servidor websocket en php.
Mi idea es que la parte de php sea muy simple y que todo lo que es consultas a la base de datos sea desde el cliente.
De igual forma no entiendo lo de la seguridad integrada con Windows.
Es que no quiero hacer una api en php porque de esta forma cualquiera podría usarla y solo quiero que desde el cliente se pueda pero esto no es posible al parecer.

Comment: @LucasBarrena Mi opinión es que deberías usar servicios WCF o algún tipo de API REST donde expongas todo lo que tu aplicación de escritorio deba hacer. Es evidente que cualquiera podría consumir esos servicios, pero también es cierto que deberás establecer los controles de seguridad adecuados (mediante autenticación y tokens puedes limitar la API y nadie podrá usarla si no quieres) Yo personalmente no veo ningún inconveniente en aplicar esa solución.

Comment: Concuerdo con @Sergio en ese sentido. Si quieres proteger tu BBDD lo mejor es crear un web service (WCF preferiblemente) dónde definas tus operaciones y dónde haya la conexión a la BBDD. de esta manera ya lo tienes solucionado.

Comment: Mm, pues entonces seguiré desarrollando la aplicación y veré que tal va.
En php tendré un script corriendo 24hs donde estará el servidor websocket en línea. Este websocket lo utilizaré para la comunicación entre clilente y servidor, creo que es mas rápido que hacer peticiones post, get, put, delete.
O sea, todas las peticiones de la api van a ser dirigidas como mensajes hacia el socket y de ahí manejaré todo.
Está bien o mal?

Comment: Una duda, suponiendo que la conexión con el socket es segura (wss/https) no tengo que preocuparme de encriptar el mensaje que envíe desde el cliente al servidor? miedo a sniffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según he leído en los comentarios, estás desarrollando una aplicación de Escritorio que se conectaría directamente a una base de datos de MySQL.

Estos casos son difíciles de securizar porque te obliga a tener el usuario y contraseña de MySQL en el cliente, que aunque lo guardes encriptado, un usuario malintencionado podría dar con ellos y acceder directamente a la base de datos.

Para evitar esto se podría establecer la seguridad mediante las credenciales de Windows (Autenticación integrada) pero eso tampoco no está libre de problemas:

- Esta funcionalidad solo está disponible para la [edición Enterprise](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-authentication-plugin.html) de MySQL (en SQL Server si que está, incluso en la edición gratuita)
- Algún usuario "listillo" podría acceder directamente a la base de datos, con sus credenciales, sin pasar por la aplicación

Por lo tanto, coincido con varios comentarios que recomiendan no realizar la conexión directa sino pasar por una API intermedia cuyo acceso debe estar protegido (para esto se suele usar [seguridad basada en tokens](https://carlosazaustre.es/blog/que-es-la-autenticacion-con-token/))

Para la implementación de esta API, [OData Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn448365(v=vs.118).aspx) podría ser buena opción.

En cuanto lo que comentas de usar la comunicación de Websockets para todo no sé si es buena idea, se suele usar más para notificaciones o actualizaciones de datos para visualizarlos en tiempo real y quizás te complique el desarrollo.

También te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a [SignalR](http://www.variablenotfound.com/2012/01/introduccion-signalr-i-conceptos.html) que es una librería .NET que simplifica mucho las cominicaciones en tiempo real con Websockets y pudría facilitarte el uso desde la aplicación cliente en C#.

Comment: Entiendo, tengo una duda, como puedo reconocer con websocket (php) que el usuario se está conectado desde mi aplicación en c# y no desde una web u otra plataforma por así decirlo?
O sea, el servidor websocket se estaría ejecutando en php y yo quiero desde php saber desde que "plataforma" se conecta el cliente (por ejemplo, Web).. en el caso de que sea Web yo desconectaría a dicho cliente ya que la aplicación no tendría aplicación web y en el caso de que tenga yo manejaría que hacer con tal cliente.

Comment: Hola @LucasBarrena, lo que tendrías que hacer es implementar un mecanismo de seguridad para que solo los usuarios autorizados establezcan conexión con el WebSocket,  en [este](http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/security/how-to-create-a-secure-websocket-connection.html) artículo (en inglés) habla del tema. En [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security) está más integrado

Comment: @LucasBarrena, por cierto, lo de averiguar desde que plataforma se ha establecido la conexión quizás se podría saber accediendo al `user-agent` pero tampoco es seguro porque se puede falsificar. También se podría enviar un encabezado HTTP para diferenciarlas

Comment: Gracias por la información, me será de útil :)

Comment: Hola. Aparte de todo lo comentado por los compañeros. Te recomiendo que los datos sensibles como usuarios y contraseñas las almacenes en [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Buena observación, recuerdo que lo había leído! gracias :)